# How to restrict number of quizzes that somebody can take in a day

Tags: 7, quiz

I am new to quiz module. I wanted to restrict the users, in a way, they can take only a particular number of quizzes in a day. For example a user with name 'A' can take only 'x' number of quizzes in a day, and after that if somebody tries, should end up with a warning message 'Try tomorrow again'.

Anybody has come up with such ideas?. If not how can I achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the quiz module myself but I think I would start with a custom module using HOOK_form_alter() to call a function that would parse the UID from quizzes where the published time is within the last 24 hrs. If you find more than 5 then you block access or redirect. This is just to get you started. I have not tested it.

```
function current_quizes(){
    //Get today's date.
    $today = getdate();

    //Get current time.
    $end_time = time();

    //Get the current user
    $current_user = $user->uid;

    //Calculate the date yesterday.
    $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0,$today['mon'],($today['mday'] - 1), $today['year']);

    //You will have to tweak the DB query based on how the quiz module stores its information
    $query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n')
        ->condition('status', 1) //Published.
        ->condition('created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN') //in the last 24hrs
        ->condition('uid', $user->uid) //This is our guy
        ->execute(); 

    $tests_taken = 0;
    foreach ($query as $value){
        ++$tests_taken; //Every entry is a test taken in the last 24hrs
    }

    return $tests_taken;  //Return total tests taken
}
```